# htaccess does not understand ^www\. rule , if paramters are appended to url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

.htaccess does not understand `^www\.` rule

```
#do not use this, because i want to redirect from https://www.somedomain.com
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^somedomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.somedomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/somedomain\.com" [L,R=301]
#[NE,L,R=301] - NE|noescape
```

This gives the following redirections, though very slow:

somedomain.com  -->  https://somedomain.com

www.somedomain.com  -->  https://www.somedomain.com

somedomain.com/folder/file  -->  https://somedomain.com/folder/file

www.somedomain.com/folder/file  -->  http://www.somedomain.com/folder/file

the last url www.somedomain.com/folder/file is not redirected to https. WHY?

Comment: Does `^/?$`  match `folder/file` …? (Your second to last example should not be working with this either.)

Answer (score 0):

You have an additional condition with `[OR]` that can cause too many redirects. Fix it by using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.somedomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://somedomain.com [L,R=301]
```

Completely clear browser cache before testing this.

Comment: i need it, how i can redirect from somedomain.com if i have no OR? I have tried, without OR somedomain.com is not redirected to https

Comment: No you don't need it. Think through it all the conditions. This will redirect **ANY** of the `http://www.somedomain.com`, `https://www.somedomain.com`, `http://somedomain.com` to `https://somedomain.com`. What else do you need?

Comment: You seem to have lot of unnecessary code in your ,htaccess causing problems for you. Post your full .htaccess in your question so that I can investigate and suggest accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This works will all urls with parameters and without. 
And it is true, it is very important to clear cache and try to relaod page several times, in several different browsers. Otherwise, some old rules may apply.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^somedomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.somedomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://somedomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Results are :

somedomain.com --> https://somedomain.com

www.somedomain.com --> https://www.somedomain.com

somedomain.com/folder/file --> https://somedomain.com/folder/file

www.somedomain.com/folder/file --> https://www.somedomain.com/folder/file

TO make things faster:

```
DirectoryIndex /index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^typejoy\.biz$ 
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^typejoy\.biz$ [OR]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.typejoy\.biz$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://typejoy.biz%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.typejoy\.biz$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://typejoy.biz%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.typejoy\.biz$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://typejoy.biz%{REQUEST_URI} [L, NE,R=301]
```

i believe you should not not put `L` if there are more rules

Comment: Why use `%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}` in question and `%{HTTPS}` in answer?